# Correlation plots not built when using create_report

Tags: r

When I use `plot_correlation(df)` it works but when I use `create_report(df, config = config)` with `config<- list("plot_correlation" = list())`, it doesn't though all other plots (except of PCA) are processed successfully.

Within the report I receive

> Correlation Analysis
>
> ### Insufficient complete rows! Skipping correlation analysis.

instead. Any idea?

Comment: I tried using `df <- iris` and it worked. I got a `report.html` file in the working directory with the correlation plot.

Comment: So it must be the data. But why does it work outside of create_report? Any idea where I could look after?